# Mongodb docs failing to build in Docker

Tags: python, mongodb, docker

I'm attempting to use the following Dockerfile to build a local copy of the MongoDB documentation like so:

```
FROM python:2 as builder
RUN ["mkdir", "/pythonsrc"]
WORKDIR "/pythonsrc"
RUN ["git", "clone", "https://github.com/mongodb/docs.git", "."]
RUN ["pip", "install", "-r", "requirements.txt"]
RUN ["make", "html"]

# FROM nginx:stable
# COPY --from=builder /pythonsrc/docs/_build/html /usr/share/nginx/html
```

but it's failing at the `RUN ["make", "html"]` step with the following error:

```
INFO:giza.operations.make:running sphinx build operation, equivalent to: giza sphinx --builder html
INFO:giza.content.assets:cloned master branch from repo https://github.com/mongodb/docs-tools.git
INFO:giza.content.system:migration: source/.static/10gen-gpg-key.asc --> /pythonsrc/build/public/10gen-gpg-key.asc
INFO:giza.content.system:migration: source/.static/10gen-security-gpg-key.asc --> /pythonsrc/build/public/10gen-security-gpg-key.asc
INFO:giza.content.source:created directory for sphinx build: /pythonsrc/build/master/source
ERROR:giza.pool:caught error "[Errno 2] No such file or directory" in migrating source to build/master/source <function transfer_source at 0x7f7e3d0192d0>, waiting for other tasks to finish
ERROR:giza.pool:[OSError(2, 'No such file or directory')]
```

Getting a shell into the container with `docker run --rm -it <containerhere> /bin/bash` and inspecting the filesystem shows that `/pythonsrc/build/master/source` does indeed exist, and has even been written to so I'm not sure where this error is coming from.

The only Google result brings me to this post https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/DOCS-11909, and checking the availability of `sphinx-build` in the container as suggested doesn't show anything out of the ordinary:

```
root@0ab5373268a4:/pythonsrc# which sphinx-build
/usr/local/bin/sphinx-build
root@0ab5373268a4:/pythonsrc# head -n1 `which sphinx-build`
#!/usr/local/bin/python
root@0ab5373268a4:/pythonsrc# which python
/usr/local/bin/python
root@0ab5373268a4:/pythonsrc# python
**Python 2.7.18** (default, Apr 20 2020, 19:27:10)
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Has anyone else encountered this error? Is there a fix / workaround for this?